# Shift in right array without loop in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, loops, shift

Can I shift an array[9] in right without using loops?

For example:

I have an array like this

```
{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', '?', '?', '?'}
```

I would like to change my array in this

```
{'?', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', '?', '?'}
```

Is there any solution that doesn't shift each char with a loop? Also recursion is not a good solution cause i want save time in algorithm.

Comment: use some modulo access ?

Comment: Yes, you can shift each char with recursion. Or with `goto`. Or by calling `memmove`, which contains a loop, but you can't see it.

Comment: Since the length is fixed, just manually unroll the loop.

Comment: As said, with `memmove` but be careful with its `count` argument (consider the element size and how many elements are to be moved). Pick up the last array element first, afterwards write it to the first element.

Comment: Can you be flexible about the representation? A linked-list of `char`s would do it in `O(1)`.

Comment: How about a ring buffer? You can change head and tail index.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/146984). What is the larger problem you're trying to solve that makes you think you need to shift the array?

Comment: A `union` with `uint64_t` (C99 on supported platforms) will fit a `char array[8]`, but @FiddlingBits suggestion is probably what you want.

Comment: @NeilEdelman Ring buffer prevents use of the standard string functions which might  be a problem.

Comment: with big enough preallocated space  you can just decrement the array pointer instead (`O(1)`) and set the first char ... but that will limit the number of possible rotations ...

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to do it manually like this:
aux=V [0]
V [0]=V [1]
......
V [7]=V [8]
V [8]=aux
There is no better way (regarding optimisation) to do things than to manually implement them.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef union 
{
    uint64_t u;
    char c[8];
}silly_union;


typedef struct 
{
    size_t cpos;
    char buff[1024];
}even_worse;

typedef enum 
{
    RIGHT,
    LEFT,
    CENTRE,
}alignment;

even_worse *init(const char *str, alignment a)
{
    even_worse *ew = malloc(sizeof(*ew));
    if(ew)
    {
        switch(a)
        {
            case RIGHT:
                strcpy(ew -> buff[(ew -> cpos = sizeof(ew -> buff) - 2 - strlen(str))], str);
                break;
            case CENTRE:
                strcpy(ew -> buff[(ew -> cpos = sizeof(ew ->buff) / 2 - 1 - strlen(str) / 2)], str);
                break;
            case LEFT:
                strcpy(ew -> buff, str);
                ew -> cpos = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    return ew;
}

char *shiftright(even_worse *ew)
{
    if(ew -> cpos)
    {
        ew -> cpos--;
        return ew -> buff[ew -> cpos];
    }
    return NULL;   
}

int shiftleft(even_worse *ew)
{
    if(ew -> cpos < sizeof(ew -> buff) - 1)
    {
        ew -> cpos++;
        return ew -> buff[ew -> cpos];
    }
    return NULL;   
}


int main()
{
    silly_union su = {.c = "hello"};

    su.u <<= 8; // little endian oppsite direction :)

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(su); i++)
    {
        printf("Char No: %zu = `%c` (%hhd)\n", i, su.c[i] > 32 && su.c[i] < 127 ? su.c[i] : ' ', su.c[i]);
    }

/*tests for even worse write yourself :)*/
}
```